# C# showdialog and this.close does not meet expectations because background is seen for a second when new window is shown

Tags: c#, window, showdialog

I'm using this code to open one window and close the other one. Its working but the problem is when one window is closed and the other one is opened background is seen for 1 second. I don't want it to be seen how can I solve it ? Should I use usercontrol and change it ? I don't want to use multiple usercontrols in one page because it complicates the program. So any other simple solution I would be glad.

```
    private void backPageButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mWin = new MainWindow();
        this.Close();
        mWin.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Here is my code simple and When I change the orders like this

```
 private void backPageButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mWin = new MainWindow();
        mWin.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

then it creates windows continually.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve with closing the windows. You can also use Visible to hide windows. The ShowDialog method will block until the created windows is closed.

Comment: are both windows of the same type?

Comment: Why ShowDialog?  Use Show().

Answer (score 1):

This would do it, use the second window to close the first

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow(MainWindow otherWindow) : this()
        {
            if (otherWindow != null)
            {
                otherWindow.Close();
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mWin = new MainWindow(this);
            mWin.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. guessing you are trying to make a wizard style set of dialogs from the name of your button, I've had recent success using the [WPF Toolkit Wizard control](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wizard).

Comment: Logical but didnt solve the problem Still background is seen for a second when the other window is started.

Comment: Didn't notice it on mine but could have been perception on a fast pc. How about save the otherWindow reference from the constructor, hook into the Loaded event and do the Close() there?

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
private void backPageButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    MainWindow mWin = new MainWindow();
    mWin.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```